# Navigation links length based on window height

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navbar that floats at the top of the page. For some menu options, a long list of links is necessary. For higher resolution monitors, this is fine. For lower resolution monitors, it's not because not all the links are visible.

I want a scrollbar for the list of links to appear for those with lower resolutions or shorter window heights. I've tried using various methods of setting the height and overflow options for the `ul` tag. A fixed height isn't going to work obviously. I've tried setting different `vh` values, but that doesn't seem to do what I want either.

```
<li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">OPTIONS</a>
    <ul style="height: auto; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 15</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 16</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 17</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 18</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 19</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 20</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Time for this again. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Have you tried setting up a media query for lower resolutions and giving the `ul` tag the property `overflow:scroll`?

Also try adding `white-space:nowrap` to 'ul' as well.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries